Recursively list dependencies of an uninstalled package in arch linux
As per Recursively list dependencies of a package in arch linux, but for uninstalled/not yet installed packages now, for which pactree does not work.
Background: I've been trying to install the utter eldritch nightmare that is pytorch-lightning again for a week and I'd like to debug which of the 10,000 dependencies is spurious. (Probably, most of them), and which AUR package is to blame for making optional dependencies required, and causing it to pull in not just torch, but also tensorflow and Jax and pretty much every other machine learning package under the sun through that. (Pretty sure It shouldn't need either Jax or Tensorflow)
